# Can I filter items displayed in RepositoryItemLookUpEdit?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, user-interface, devexpress

Here's some of my code:

```
List<Targets> _myList = new List<Targets>();
RepositoryItemLookUpEdit MyRepositoryItemLookUpEdit = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit();
MyRepositoryItemLookUpEdit.DataSource = _myList;

public class Targets
{
    public string Target { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldDisplay { get; set; }
    public Targets(string target)
    {
        Target = target;
        ShouldDisplay = true;
    }
}
```

**My question:** is it possible that when the dropdown list is displayed, only the Targets with `ShouldDisplay == true` are shown?

Notice that `_myList` can be accessed by event handlers, so items in the list and the `ShouldDisplay` property of them are modified at run time. For example:

```
public void MyGrid_CellValueChanging(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (/* the focused Target item appears more than 3 times in the grid*/)
    { 
        thisTarget.ShouldDisplay = false; // so it will be visually removed from the lookUpEdit and the user cannot select the same one anymore
    }
}
```

BTW, assignment to DataSource inside CellValueChanging event handler is not appropriate, because the any changes made by user would be discarded once DataSource is reassigned.

Comment: why are you assigning this = new List<Targets>();?

Comment: Is your problem resolved using my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
MyRepositoryItemLookUpEdit.DataSource = new List<Targets>();//i can't get why you are assigning empty list
```

To

```
//your list which is List<Targets> and contains values. Not the empty one like above
MyRepositoryItemLookUpEdit.DataSource = yourList.Where(x=>x.ShouldDisplay ).ToList();
```

**Edit**:

After your edit of question, you need to implement

> [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

interface. Then whenever the value of ShouldDisplay is changed you need to rebind. See a working example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15822/Bind-Better-with-INotifyPropertyChanged)

Comment: Hey thanks Ehsan, sorry my previous question is confusing. I just modified it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If it wouldn't hinder workflow (if the data loads quickly enough to edit and reload it in real time), I'd suggest keeping the user-side data and the database data separate. You could add a bit field to the table to store whether or not an item should be displayed or not, filter the data when you get it from the database to display it initially, and then when changes are made that set ShouldDisplay to false, write that to the database, drop it from the list, and refresh the list.

Of course, with a lot of data in the list, this solution might not be feasible.

Original answer:

Ehsan's suggestion is what I was going to post. Another option would be to loop through the items in your main targetsList (whatever you would be databinding the dropdown list to) and create a new list, like this:

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>();
foreach (Targets t in targetsList)
{
    if (t.ShouldDisplay == true) { newList.Add(t.Target); }
}
```

And then databind the dropdown to newList instead of your targetsList. But I'm not sure about the exact features of the RepositoryItemLookUpEdit so this solution may not work. It's fine for when you just want to display the information, but might be more awkward if you have to interact with the data itself. All depends on what you're doing with it.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. But that's not what I want. I just modified the question description.

Comment: Where is the code that puts values into _mylist? Is the user adding them at runtime?

Comment: Yes pretty much like that. There is code that reads a table from DB and populate `_myList` at initiation.

Comment: Ah, okay. Does the table have a field for "ShouldDisplay", or is that property based on something else? If it's a field in the table you can filter the data as you populate the list, and then use what Ehsan said to re-populate and refresh the list as changes are made.

Comment: No it's not based on a table field...I am taking a look at his example right now. Thanks:)

Comment: I saw your edit...you want to set the ShouldDisplay property based on how many instances of the item exist in the list? I'm starting to understand more but your specific conditions are still a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a bindingSource and bind the RepopsitoryItemLookUpEdit to the bindingsource you don't have to reassign the datasource.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly List<Targets> _targetses;
    private BindingList<Targets> _fiList;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this._targetses = new List<Targets>();
        this._targetses.Add(new Targets("Sample"));
        this._targetses.Add(new Targets("Sample"));
        this._targetses.Add(new Targets("Sample"));
        this._targetses.Add(new Targets("Sample") {ShouldDisplay = false});

        this.bindingSource1.DataSource = this.FilteredList;
        this.lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = this.bindingSource1;
        this.bindingSource1.ListChanged += BindingSource1OnListChanged;

        this._targetses[1].ShouldDisplay = false;
    }

    public BindingList<Targets> FilteredList
    {
        get
        {
            return this._fiList ??
                   (this._fiList = new BindingList<Targets>(this._targetses.Where(x => x.ShouldDisplay).ToList()));
        }
    }

    private void BindingSource1OnListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs listChangedEventArgs)
    {
        this._fiList.Clear();
        foreach (Targets t in this._targetses.Where(x => x.ShouldDisplay)) { this._fiList.Add(t); }
    }

    #region Nested type: Targets

    public class Targets : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _bShouldDisplay;
        private string _sTarget;

        public Targets(string target)
        {
            Target = target;
            ShouldDisplay = true;
        }

        public string Target
        {
            get { return this._sTarget; }
            set
            {
                if (this._sTarget == value)
                    return;

                this._sTarget = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool ShouldDisplay
        {
            get { return this._bShouldDisplay; }
            set
            {
                if (this._bShouldDisplay == value)
                    return;

                this._bShouldDisplay = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Result:

[image]